# What PRNG algorithm is used in tezos?

Tags: node, baking-rights

I'm interested int the PRNG algorithm that tezos uses for drawing baking rights. It is vaguely mentioned in the docs as a **CSPRNG** (Cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator) seeded with a random seed generated from the revealed nonces. But that is all we get.

Can anyone provide some explanation how the mentioned **CSPRNG** works? Did they use a known algorithm or developed their own?

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr** it is home-made CSPRNG based on repeatedly hashing an initial
seed with [Blake2b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAKE_(hash_function)).

**Details**: The interface of this CSPRNG can be found in the protocol [here](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/master/src/proto_006_PsCARTHA/lib_protocol/seed_repr.mli), 
and the implementation [here](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/master/src/proto_006_PsCARTHA/lib_protocol/seed_repr.ml).
(Optionally, you can read the interface [here](http://tezos.gitlab.io/api/odoc/_html/tezos-protocol-006-PsCARTHA/Tezos_raw_protocol_006_PsCARTHA__Seed_repr/index.html), but the formatting is messed up.)

The function `take` generates a new random value using State_hash:

```
let take (S state) =
  let b = State_hash.to_bytes state in
  let h = State_hash.hash_bytes [b] in
  (State_hash.to_bytes h, S h)
```

`State_hash` [uses Blake2b internally](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/master/src/proto_006_PsCARTHA/lib_protocol/state_hash.ml).