# How exactly are the bakers chosen using the PRG?

Tags: node, baking, baking-rights, proof-of-stake, implementation

I understand that the seed associated with a cycle is generated from information from the previous two cycles. This seed the PRG that is used to determine the bakers for the cycle. This is all the information I can find on the [docs](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/docs/alpha/proof_of_stake.rst) regarding its implementation:

> We admit, for the time being, that the protocol generates a random
> seed for each cycle. From this random seed, we can seed a
> cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator which is used
> to draw baking rights for a cycle.

I also found [this post](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1978/what-prng-algorithm-is-used-in-tezos), which has been helpful in further details on how the PRG is constructed:

> The function take generates a new random value using State_hash.

**How exactly is this output from the PRG used to pick the bakers for the cycle?** I'm having trouble finding this in the docs/implementation, so I'm looking for an explanation and maybe a pointer to where this is in the repository.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the implementation is here: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/a88a1ed6f5da8d0f016d70ea43b6e5ec073aae12/src/proto_alpha/lib_protocol/roll_storage.ml#L159